# Return max join result only if ID matches

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to build a query that will select all tenants of a rental property. Each property can have multiple tenants, and each tenant can be moved to a different property.

Here's what (part of) the user property table looks like:

```
User ID  |  Property ID  |  Move In Date  |  Move Out Date
----------------------------------------------------------
224      |  33A          |  2015-11-01    |  NULL
224      |  36B          |  2015-11-15    |  NULL
226      |  33A          |  2015-11-01    |  NULL
```

In the example above `User 224` moved into property `33A` on the 1st, then property `36B` on the 15th. For this issue, and example, I'm assuming that the `move_out_date` column did not get properly populated with a date. In this instance I need a query that will bypass that issue.

Here's what I have for my query so far:

```
SELECT
    u.user_email, p.user_fname, p.user_lname, r.move_in_date AS occupant_date
FROM
    user u
LEFT JOIN
    user_profile p ON p.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            user_id, property_id, move_in_date
        FROM
            user_property
        WHERE
            move_out_date IS NULL
        ORDER BY
            move_in_date DESC
    ) r ON r.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE
    r.property_id = '33A'
GROUP BY
    u.user_id
ORDER BY
    r.move_in_date ASC, p.user_fname ASC
```

This query returns each occupants info, and move in date. For property `33A` it is returning Users `224` and `226`, but I only want to return User `226` because technically User `224` moved from that property.

Currently the output table looks like this:

```
User ID  |  Property ID  |  Move In Date  |  Move Out Date
----------------------------------------------------------
224      |  33A          |  2015-11-01    |  NULL
226      |  33A          |  2015-11-01    |  NULL

User ID  |  Email        |  First Name  |  Last Name  | Occupant Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------
224      |  user1@e.com  |  Kevin       |  Doe        |  2015-11-01
226      |  user2@e.com  |  Tom         |  Smith      |  2015-11-01
```

But I'd only like the results for User `226` specifically for property ID `33A`. Ultimately, this...

```
User ID  |  Email        |  First Name  |  Last Name  | Occupant Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------
226      |  user2@e.com  |  Tom         |  Smith      |  2015-11-01
```

Is this possible to do in one query, or will I need to make a couple of them? I appreciate any help on this!

Comment: means you need --->  `226      |  33A          |  2015-11-01    |  NULL`  ?? only

Comment: it will be good if you share the output table .

Comment: do you have any ID column(Auto incremented) in your table.

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode Yes, that is what I would like to get.

Comment: @Code-Monk I do not have an `auto_increment` column on that table. I actually have the key set using the User ID, Property ID, and dates. There are other fields in the table, but these are the ones specific to what I'm looking to do. I assume you're thinking I could use an `auto_increment` column, and get my results based on that?

Comment: 224 and 226 are on the same date.How do you prefer 226 over 224

Comment: @K. Doe: As per the data you have provided in your question. Both users `224` and `226` has the same `property ID` and `move in date`, then how can you say that user `226` has the latest move in that particular property.

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode I'm not trying to prefer either over the other. What I'm trying to do is only get **current** tenants for a property. Multiple tenants can live in a property, but if one moves out, and into another property, and the `move_out_date` column does not get populated properly for the previous property, then I'd like my query to solve that issue for me, if possible.

Comment: @Code-Monk I have updated my question so that it is hopefully a bit clearer. I'm sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode I have updated my question so that it is hopefully a bit clearer. I'm sorry for any confusion.

Comment: `Move Out Date`  => `NULL` means moved out??

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode If `Move Out Date` has a date in it, then that's the date they moved out. If it's `NULL` the code assumes they still live there. I'm trying to write this so that if `Move Out Date` doesn't get populated due to an error, it will find that they've moved in somewhere else and ignore that property information.

Comment: just trying to understand, of the 2 values, why do you pick 226 and not 224. What criteria guides this ?

Comment: @Tammy Read comments, moreover question once more.

Comment: @Tammy `226` is picked because he currently lives in `33A`, whereas `224` DID live in `33A`, but according to the table he moved into `36B` on the 15th, meaning he no longer lives in `33A` with `226`.

Comment: If there is a value instead of `null` in the moved out case , it will be better, as of now we cant assume if it is `moved out` or NOT, since both values are `null`

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode That's exactly what I'm trying to work around. If the value is `NULL` then the script assumes they still live there. However, if they have a `Move In Date` that is greater than another then I want that row to be the one that is used for their property information. In this case, the row that says they moved into property `36B` on the 15th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way for getting the current tenant for a given property:

```
select p.user_id, p.property_id, p.move_in_date from
user_property p
join (
    -- Get users most recent move in date.
    select max(move_in_date) move_in_date, user_id
    from   user_property
    group by user_id
) u_move_in on (p.user_id = u_move_in.user_id and p.move_in_date = u_move_in.move_in_date)
join (
    -- Get the property's most recent move in date.
    select max(move_in_date) move_in_date, property_id
    from   user_property
    where  property_id = '33A'
    group by property_id
) p_move_in on (p.property_id = p_move_in.property_id and p.move_in_date = p_move_in.move_in_date);
```

Find the user(s) with most recent move in date = property most recent move in date.

Comment: Thank you! This got me on the right track. I had to modify a little bit, but this is it. What's proper etiquette here? Do I post my completed answer somewhere?